# How can I create a object like a string, for example? A object with many properties, and a default console.log/evaluation value

Tags: javascript, object, types, getter, primitive

I want to create a object with many properties, but, when I just console.log my object or insert it into a evaluation, it does have a default value to evaluate or log, a primitive value, like "test", for example.

I tried to use getters and setters but had no sucess.

```
const obj = { a: 'test1', b: 'test2' } // this is my object

console.log(obj.a); // this should return 'test1'

console.log(obj); // this should return a value of my choice, like 'testobj' or a number

'testobj' === obj; // should be true, since I want my obj to have a default value of 'testobj' in evaluations
// just like a primitive type, like strings or numbers. They have many functions and a default value
```

Comment: Give the object a property called "toString" and assign an appropriate function to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One year later I ran into this question again and found a solution. My objective was to create a string/number with a few methods that would use itself(this) to generate the output values and could be used in your code as a normal number/string without casting or anything like that, like a normal JS number/string.

Something like a number that has its own value but you can access the number.negative property and you will have the negative equivalent to your number. You can do it creating a class that extends the primitive type that you want to use, like, for a Number, I can use:

```js
class Num extends Number {
  negative = this * (-1);
  // I can even add a few methods that receive props to calculate new output values
  exponential(exp) {
    let result = 1;
    while(exp-- > 0) {
      result *= this;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

const myNum = new Num(3);

console.log('Simple sum: ', 1 + myNum); // outputs 4

console.log('Negative: ', myNum.negative); // outputs -3

console.log('Exponential: ', myNum.exponential(2)); // outputs 9
```

The code above works for strings as well. Hope I can help someone with this.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is treated like a string, the JavaScript runtime will look to see if it has a `toString()` method and will return whatever that method indicates. If there isn't a `toString()`, then usually you'll see `[object Object]`. Also, to produce the underlying primitive value, give the object a `valueOf` value.

Additionally, when making objects that will be used in this way, use constructor functions, rather than object literals.

```js
const objA = function(){ this.a= 'test1'; this.b= 'test2' }
let instA = new objA();
console.log(instA.toString());

const objB = function() { 
  this.a= 5; 
  this.b= 'test2'; 
  this.toString= function(){ return this.a; };
  this.valueOf = function() { return this.toString(); }; 
}
let instB = new objB();
console.log(instB.toString());
console.log(instB + 2); // Get the primitive and work with that
```

Comment: I was looking for something like [[PrimitiveValue]], a property available inside string or number objects. We can see the [[PrimitiveValue]] when we enter new String('test') in the browser's console, this will return an object with a property named [[PrimitiveValue]], defining the primitive value of an object to use when needed. How can I set [[PrimitiveValue]] ?

Comment: @RafaelLopesSchneider I have updated the answer, which is to give the object a `valueOf()` method.